# Php dynamically replace placeholder variables in string

Tags: php

I want to dynamically replace placeholder variables in a string.

```
str_replace("\$", $data["Whatever follows the \$], $variable);
```

`\$` signifies a placeholder variable, `\$ID` for example.

The data I want it to be replace with is in an array. `$\ID` should be replaced with `$data['ID']`.

For example, if I have a string that says "The ID is `\$ID` and name is `\$name`". I want to replace both the \$ID and \$name with the relevant data in my `$data` object. `$\ID` would be `$data['ID']` and so on.

This needs to be dynamic. I don't want to hard code it to replace `\$ID` with `$data['ID']`. The key used to get the data in $data should be equal to what follows the `\$`.

I'm having trouble figuring out not only how to do this dynamically like I have talked about, but to do it for every `\$` in a string.

Comment: why not use printf?

Answer (score 1):

Use printf() or sprintf().

If you mark your placeholder with a number, you can repeat it any number of times in your string.

```
sprintf("This is my test string. Here's a placeholder: %1$s, and a another: %2$s, First one again: %1$s", $var1, $var2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string = 'some $ID $PARAM string';
$values = array("ID" => "idparam", "PARAM" => "p");

preg_match_all("/\\\$(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/", $string, $matches);

foreach($matches["name"] as $m) {
    if(!isset($values[$m])) {
        //TODO handling
        continue;
    }
    $string = str_replace('$'.$m, $values[$m], $string);
}

var_dump($string);
```

The keys in `$values` should be name of the parameter without the dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job for you! https://3v4l.org/XRQii

```
<?php

$string = 'The ID is \$ID and name is \$name';
$row = [
  'ID'=> 5,
  'name' => 'delboy1978uk',
];


function replaceStuff($string, $row) {
    preg_match_all('#\\$\w+#', $string, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        $key = str_replace('$', '', $match);
        $replace = '\\'.$match;
        $string = str_replace($replace, $row[$key], $string);
    }
    return $string;
}

echo replaceStuff($string, $row);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php for more info on `preg_match_all()`.